# проверить навешено ли событие на элемент

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox-extension

Установлен плагин для ff, он ищет элементы на странице все элементы с классом OOo и навешивает на них событие `click`.

```
contentLoad: function(e) {
  var anchors = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) { 
    if (/.*OOo.*/.test(anchors[i].className)) {
      anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) { OOo.onClick(e); }, false);
    }
  }
}
```

когда я гружу страницу, я не могу знать, есть ли событие на ссылке, а плагин иногда видимо пытается повешать событие в момент когда `DOM` до конца не загрузился.
В итоге приходится перегружать страницу и надеяться на то, что событие навесится.

Нет возможности править плагин, можно ли как то со стороны приложения убедиться, что событие есть, чтоб я мог показывать ссылку только тогда когда плагин сработал?

Приложение на angular 1.x

Comment: мб. какая ещё инфа нужна? буду рад любой помощи)

Comment: Написал новый плагин вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-libreoffice-%D0%B8%D0%B7-firefox-webextension/717399#717399

Comment: Если ты не можешь править плагин, то в чём смысл определения наличия события?

Comment: не совсем понятно, почему ваше приложение зависит от какого-то стороннего плагина?

Answer (score 0):

Дайте вашему обработчику события название, и можно будет либо не глядя вешать на все елементы, судя с следующего примера, срабатывает только 1н раз :

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#test');
btn.addEventListener('click', testFunc, false);
btn.addEventListener('click', testFunc, false);


function testFunc() {
  console.log('testFunc');
};
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```

или (при наличии имени функции) можно сначала удалить обработчик а потом повешать его, как-то так :

```
contentLoad: function(e) {
  var anchors = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) { 
    if (/.*OOo.*/.test(anchors[i].className)) {
      anchors[i].removeEventListener("click", someFunc);
      anchors[i].addEventListener("click", someFunc, false);
    }
  }
}

function someFunc(e){
  OOo.onClick(e);
};
```

Comment: так в том и проблема, что я править на стороне плагина не могу, а eventы вешает плагин, мб я как то могу прогрузить DOM до того как плагин сработает, вот ссылка на плагин мб поможет https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/openofficeorg-for-jacare-proje/?src=userprofile

Comment: @ЮрийПудуль а этот кусок кода в вопросе, это откуда ?

Comment: из плагина, его как раз править не могу

Comment: так выглядит ссылка на которую должно повешаться событие <a class="OOo" href="{{baseUrl}}/webdav/{{vm.stage.dataId}}/{{vm.stage.dataName}}" target="document">
            {{vm.stage.dataName}}
        </a>

Comment: судя по всему (исходя из того что я подгуглил немного), проверить есть ли ивентлистенер в js не получится, прийдется ращитывать на то что плагин справится с задачей, и еще, как он запускается на странице то ?